# What datatype to use when storing metric data in SQL databases?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to store metric data (meters, kilometers, square-meters) in SQL Server 2012.

What is the best datatype to use? `float` (C#: double), `decimal` (C#: decimal) or even `geometry`? Or something different?

Comment: How much precision do you need?

Comment: @Ren I don't really know. My guess would be two, because a precision of "150,00 meters", "150 squaremeters" or "12,93 Kilometers" would be sufficient

Comment: It depends.... What are you going to do with the data?

Comment: @ColinMackay Not much. Simple comparison, of (let's say) "20 squaremeter <= 50 squaremeter". It is mostly used within an application based on real estate data

Comment: It completely depends on the application. Ar we talking architecture or points on the earth's surface?

Comment: Have a look here for different available data types that can be used - http://i.stack.imgur.com/HKZCS.gif Not sure about which one best suits your needs though as I thought decimal until someone mentioned that it is slow.

Comment: @AvadaKedavra We're talking about real estates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It completely depends on the application and what precision you need for it.

If we are talking about architecture then then precision needs are relatively limited and a `C# 32-bit float` will take you a long way. In SQL this translates to `float(24)`, also referred to as the database type `real`. This SQL DB type requires 4 bytes of storage per entry.

If we instead want to address points on the surface of the earth you need a lot higher precision. Here a `C# double` is suitable, which corresponds to a `SQL float(53)` or just `float`. This SQL DB type requires 8 bytes of storage and should be used only if needed or if the application is small and disk/memory usage is not a concern.

The `SQL Decimal` is could be a good alternative for the actual SQL DB, but has 2 drawbacks:

1. It corresponds to a `C# Decimal` which is a type designed for financial usage and to prevent round-off errors. This design renders the C# Decimal type slower than a float/double when used in trigonometric methods etc. You could of course cast this back and forth in your code, but that is not the most straight-forward approach IMO.

> "The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations requiring large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors." - [MSDN : Decimal Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)
>
> The SQL DB type `Decimal` requires 5-9 bytes of storage per entry (depending on the precision used), which is larger than the float(x) alternatives.
>
> So, use it according to your needs. In your comment you state that its about real estate,  so I'd go for `float(24)` (aka `real`) which is exactly 4 bytes and directly translates to a `C# float`. See: [float and real (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)

Lastly, here is a helpful resource for converting different types between .Net and SQL: [SqlDbType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx)

Comment: What is `float` in SQL without any precision specified and why is `decimal`'s precision not enough? Wouldn't `decimal` be a lot faster if it has a lower precision than `float`?

Comment: SQL float corresponds (somewhat) to a C# double. That is it has a quite high precession. C# float in SQL is called a ´real´, which is the same as a ´float(24)´. SQL Decimal corresponds to a C# Decimal, which is designed for financial needs and "slower" than a C# double.

Comment: And what is a `float` without a specified pecision? What's the default precision of a `float`? My SQL Column has the type `float` and not `float(24)`

Comment: float without any specified precision is equal to float(53) aka C# double.

Comment: Okay, so for real estates (square-meters), you'd suggest a `float(24)` (or `real` - which of them is the most common?) in SQL, thereby a C# `float`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that would be my pick. And real is somewhat considered old-school, so I'd use float(24).

Comment: Okay, I think that's considered a perfect solution. Thank you. I'll still wait a few more hours and will mark your reply as the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Either a `decimal` with an appropriate amount of precision for your data, or an `int` type, if appropriate

Comment: Decimal is good for accountancy, but metric units of length and area? Perhaps not. Especially, if you are going to be using trig functions. Decimal is quite slow, so you should only use it if you absolutely need it.

Comment: "Avoid using float or real columns in WHERE clause search conditions, especially the =..." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this assertion that decimal is "Slow" - I'm not seeing any difference on a 100,000 row table.

Comment: There are various documents noting that decimal is slower than floating point in its pure form. In the context of SQL Server, you are probably right that the difference is negligible because SQL Server is spending proportionately more of its time pulling data around memory or disk rather performing calculations or comparisons on it. The questioner needs to also take into account its use outside of SQL Server, not just its storage.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do
float or double are non-exact datatypes (so 5.0 == 5.0 may be false due to rounding issues)
Decimal is an exact datatype (so 5.0 == 5.0 will always be true)
and Geometry/Geography (easy said) are for locations on a map.

Float calculation should be fastes among the three, since geography is binary data with some infomation about projection (ist all about maps here) and decimal technically not as easy to handle as float.